# mssql_num_rows error, but query works

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

Hi I am writing to a remote MSSQL 2005 server from a php application, and have a situation where mssql_num_rows errors out with the "mssql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" message.... but I can't figure out why

```
$writeitem = "INSERT INTO RebateSubmissionProducts VALUES ('" . $buyproduct . "'," . $quantity . ",CAST('" . $itemUUID . "' as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER),CAST('" . $eligible . "' as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER),CAST('" . $prodID . "' as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER),CAST('" . $UUID . "' as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER),NULL)";

$itemresult = mssql_query($writeitem);
if (!mssql_num_rows($itemresult)){
    echo 'Problem writing to RebateSubmissionProducts';
} else {
    echo 'Success writing to RebateSubmissionProducts';
}
mssql_free_result($itemresult);
```

The upshot is that I get the error message, but the insert works fine.

BTW all the input is run through HTMLPurifier so don't slag me too hard about that.  The hosting company can't set up PDO_DBLIB so I can't use PDO/bound params....  I also don't have access to the MS server for creating a stored procedure.

Any ideas why php thinks that $itemresult is a boolean? (both mssql_num_rows and mssql_free_result issue the same error message)

Comment: mssql_query returns a boolean if the query failed; try running `mssql_get_last_message()` to see what the error message from the database was.

Comment: That is the weird part - the record is inserted, with all the data the way I wanted it...  I just tried mssql_get_last_message() and the message was empty

Comment: That is odd; have you tried running `mssql_get_last_message()` to see if there's anything in there anyway?

Comment: so - I just tried mssql_get_last_message() and the message was empty.  And the record was added.

Comment: Oh, this is ringing a bell now. Can you run `var_dump($itemresult)` and see what it returns?

Comment: Ah.... mssql_query returns a false if the query fails. I see that so many times that I forget the first part - it also returns a boolean `true` if the query succeeds, but there are no rows to retrieve. And since you're running an INSERT, there are no rows to retrieve; so if you change your if statement to `if ($itemresult !== TRUE) { `

Comment: Thats it!  bool(true) was the response

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 0):

As [andrewsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315962/andrewsi) pointed out, mssql_num_rows() responds in a different way depending on the query.  In my case, I was running an insert, and so when this ran:

```
$itemresult = mssql_query($writeitem);
```

$itemresult was boolean(TRUE) beacuse the insert succeeded, so mssql_num_rows (and mssql_free_result() both issued warnings since there wasn't a result set.